# Clojure read file or spreadsheet

Tags: clojure, fileinputstream

I need help on how to read .xlsx files in clojure. I found this library [docjure](https://github.com/mjul/docjure) and can't run their sample code as below.

```clj
(->> (load-workbook "sample.xlsx")
     (select-sheet "Price List")
     (select-columns {:A :name, :B :price}))
```

Running the above code throws a FileNotFoundException from the core.clj file even though i am sure the "sample.xlsx" exists in the same directory as core.clj. 
I think the issue is reading the file and would appreciate help in doing so but i am open to suggestions too, thanks.

Comment: Files are resolved relative to the current directory of the executing process, not the source file. If you're running this within a repl you will need to add the relative path to the directory containing `core.clj` (e.g. "src/project/sample.xlsx"), or use a fully-qualified path. You can find the current directory of the REPL process with `(.getAbsolutePath (clojure.java.io/file "."))` if you're unsure.